# Flexslider after event not working

Tags: flexslider

I have implemented Flexslider on a template and now I'm trying to make the containing div's height to be the same with the active image's height. I was thinking of doing so by using the after function, however the after event is being ignored. I am testing it at this moment only with an alert which I understand should popup after each slide. However, the slider isn't working at all

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
   animation: "fade",
   controlNav: true,
   directionNav: true,
   controlsContainer: ".flexslider",
   directionNav: false,
   controlNav: true,
   after: function(slider){
     alert("Test");
    };
  });   
 });
```

If someone could help me with the before and after events - from what I have seen they are used to do some actions/stuff before and after a slide loads. However, in this case the after event is not working.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the setting of...

```
smoothHeight: true
```